# Se puede cancelar un delay de una manera simple javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function botonpresionado() {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
              console.log("en 5segundos te redirecciona...");
              document.getElementsByName("login")[0].click()
            },
            2000);
```

tengo una funcion la cual se ejecuta al presionar un boton y ejecuta un redireccionamiento con delay.

Mi duda, ¿con javascript existe una función para para desactivar, reactivar dicho delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con [Window clearTimeout() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp).

**Ejemplo:**

```
var myTimer;
function botonpresionado() {
     var myTimer=   setTimeout(
            function() {
              console.log("en 5segundos te redirecciona...");
              document.getElementsByName("login")[0].click()
            },
            2000);
//Encargada de detener timeout.
function detenerTimer(){
  clearTimeout(myTimer);
}
```

**Editado:** te dejo un segundo ejemplo ahora que entiendo mejor lo que tratas de hacer. En el siguiente ejemplo tienes  la opción de llamar a una función para pausar el timmer y luego si lo deseas puedes usar otra para reanudar. Para reanudar solo debes asignar el valor inicial nuevamente a la variable "c"

**Ejemplo 2**

```js
var c = 5;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = "redireccionando en "+c+"...";
  c = c - 1;
  t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
  //Si se cumple el tiempo lo redireccionamos.
  if(c==0){
     stopCount();
     //redireccionar...
     console.log("redireccionado");
  }
}

function startCount() {
  if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = 1;
    timedCount();
  }
}

function stopCount() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  timer_is_on = 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="startCount()">Start count!</button>
<button onclick="c=5">Reiniciar</button>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button onclick="stopCount()">Stop count!</button>
```

Comment: Gracias , este me quita el tiempo de espera pero no lo congela, ni me permite la reactivacion...

Comment: habria de setear el mytimer  y darle un valor con cada segundo que pasa y guardarlo al ejecutar esa funcion?

Comment: ya edité la respuesta agregando la posiblidad de pausar y reiniciar. Saludos!